# Is onPause() guaranteed to be called, even when force closing the app process?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have searched through the answers, but havent found what I am looking for.
My question is if the onPause method, or any other lifecycle method will be called if for example the process of my app is forcibly closed, like with some TaskKiller app, or with the Stop button in DDMS in Eclipse?
I need to know because I am saving valuable information in onPause

Comment: No. If the user force closes it, none of the rest of your code will execute.

Comment: so how can I save valuable information if that occurs?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do so. The best you can do is to display a highly visible warning that force closing the app will cause the lose of critical data.

Comment: One solution that just came to mind is to periodically store your data to some place more permanent. This can minimize the amount of data lose.

Comment: yes thats understandable, but you then will have to define what period you have to save it in, and how....

Comment: exactly. This is analogous to how word processor software restores your work if Word exits unexpectedly before you saved your file.

Comment: well seems like we'll just have to go with the hope that users wont force stop the apps, and warning them in the Info of the app not to do it

Comment: Apart from periodically saving the data, you can also save data whenever the user does something (e.g. whenever user adds/deletes something).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `onPause()` nor any other code in your app will execute when the user force-closes your app.

Comment: you have any sources for this?